# Spring Boot microservices - dependency

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

There are two microservices deployed with docker compose. A dependecy between services is defined in docker compose file by `depends_on` property. Is it possible to achieve the same effect implicitly, inside the spring boot application?

Let's say the microservice 1 depends on microservice 2. Which means, microsearvice 1 doesn't boot up before microservice 2 is healthy or registered on Eureka server.

Comment: You could use https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#the-bootstrap-application-context to wait for the service to become available.; however in my opinion this should be an infrastructure concern and should be dealt with there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing some research, I found a solution to the problem.

[Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) resolves dependency on Spring Cloud Config Server. Maven dependency spring-retry should be added into the pom.xml, and the properties below into the .properties file:

```
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-interval=2000
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-attempts=10
```

The following configuration class is used to resolve dependency on other microservices.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "depends-on")
@Data
@Log
public class DependsOnConfig {

    private List<String> services;
    private Integer periodMs = 2000;
    private Integer maxAttempts = 20;

    @Autowired
    private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

    @Bean
    public void dependentServicesRegisteredToEureka() throws Exception {
        if (services == null || services.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("No dependent services defined.");
            return;
        }
        log.info("Checking if dependent services are registered to eureka.");
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!services.isEmpty()) {
            services.removeIf(this::checkIfServiceIsRegistered);
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(periodMs);
            if (maxAttempts.intValue() == ++attempts)
                throw new Exception("Max attempts exceeded.");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkIfServiceIsRegistered(String service) {
        try {
            eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka(service, false);
            log.info(service + " - registered.");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(service + " - not registered yet.");
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

A list of services that the current microservice depends on are defined in .properties file:

```
depends-on.services[0]=service-id-1 
depends-on.services[1]=service-id-2
```

A bean `dependentServicesRegisteredToEureka` is not being initialized until all services from the list register to Eureka. If needed, annotation `@DependsOn("dependentServicesRegisteredToEureka")` can be added to beans or components to prevent attempting an initialization before `dependentServicesRegisteredToEureka` initialize.

Comment: Also, I found it useful to reduce `eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds` property to 10s because the default value is the 90s and it's too long to wait for registry refresh.